# Is it possible to turn a one-column unordered list into a two column unordered list withjQuery/CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

Basically, I want to turn the first 'Categories' list of the screenshot below into something like the second 'Categories' list (two columns):

[image]

Is it possible to archieve this with jQuery or CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily by floating your list items left and setting a width on both the ul and the lis

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wesbos/dcqdr/

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm too dumb, but that was simple and exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: Sometimes the best solutions are the easiest :) Be sure to check as right answer.

Answer (score 2):

With CSS3  you can create multiple columns very easily.

```
   ul{
    -moz-column-count: 2; -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 2; column-gap: 10px;
    }
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/ESPUU/

Answer (score 1):

I set up an example here.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Jbnf/

Basically, you can determine how many columns you'd like by setting the width of the un-ordered list (ul) and dividing that by how many you want.

The example I set up currently has two columns, 250px for the `ul` and 125px for each `li` item. 250 / 125 = 2.

EDIT: Wes beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes. Put all items objects into array with **$(el).each()**. Delete this element, then with **for** output 2 lists: From X to Y, from Y to Z.